# Setting up a Linux client for OpenLDAP over SSL

Tags: ubuntu, redhat, ubuntu-10.04, openldap, openssl

I'm trying to set up SSL with a server running OpenLDAP (and using OpenSSL, not GnuTLS).

The server seems to be working fine: I can authenticate using `ldap://` and can also use `ldaps://` from Apache Directory Studio. I can use LDAPS from the client as well, as long as I have this setting in /etc/ldap.conf:

```
tls_checkpeer no
```

As soon as I try to use `tls_checkpeer yes` the SSL connection is refused.

I have the following settings on the server:

```
olcTLSCACertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
olcTLSCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/private/newcert.pem
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/newreq.pem
```

The client has these related entries:

```
# ssl on
uri ldaps://192.168.1.15
tls_checkpeer no
# tls_cacertdir /etc/ssl/certs
# tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
```

The file /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem is accessible to users for reading. With the above configuration, it works. If I uncomment one of the two commented `tls_*` configuration entries and change to `tls_checkpeer yes` it fails.

I've tried using both cacert.pem and newcert.pem for the certificate (`tls_cacertfile`) and it didn't work. The cacert.pem has a `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` section, as does newcert.pem.

However, the cacert.pem has this under `X509v3 extensions`:

```
X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
    CA:TRUE
```

...and the newcert.pem file has this in the same section:

```
X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
    CA:FALSE
Netscape Comment: 
    OpenSSL Generated Certificate
```

Other certificates in /etc/ssl/certs have nothing in them except the block marked by `BEGIN CERTIFICATE`.

Using this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect 192.168.6.144:636 -showcerts
```

I can see the contents of cacert.pem and newcert.pem being used for the session.

I've not made changes to /etc/ldap/ldap.conf on either the client or the server.

Errors from the client include:

```
Feb  8 14:32:24 foo nscd: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com - Can't contact LDAP server
Feb  8 14:32:24 foo nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://bar: Can't contact LDAP server
Feb  8 14:32:24 foo nscd: nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable
```

There's no special log entries on the server. The client is Ubuntu Lucid Lynx 10.04, as is the server. All are using nscd.

Attempting to replicate the problem on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.7 system fails in the opposite direction: something that should probably fail, does not: using `tls_checkpeer yes` with an empty `tls_cacertdir` directory. I need SSL to work on both systems; we have a mix of both Ubuntu and RHEL.

I restarted nscd after each configuration change.

These are my actual questions:

- How do I get the `tls_checkpeer` option working? (main question)
- Does `ssl on` actually do anything on the client?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesnt like your cert, guessing its self signed, and the `cacert.pem` is the CA cert you used to sign it. Also the man page I'm looking at says that the parameter to specify your cacert with in `ldap.conf` is `TLS_CACERT`, not `tls_cacertfile` (whether case matters, I cant remember).

Comment: There are two `ldap.conf` files: `/etc/ldap.conf` and `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`. My understanding is that `TLS_CACERT` would be in the latter, and `tls_cacertfile` would be in the former. It is also my understanding that the former is for LDAP clients like PAM and NSS, and the latter is for the LDAP server (but I could be wrong about that.)

Comment: Many of the options are compatable between the two. And all LDAP libraries ignore options that they dont know. This is why on all our systems at work we symlink all the ldap.conf files to point at a single file. However you are correct, the man page for that option is the openldap version. For some reason I thought you were using `ldapsearch` to test this with, but going back and re-reading, I apparently made that bit up :-P

Answer (score 2):

In both client and server try adding the following to /etc/ldap/ldap.conf

```
TLS_REQCERT never
```

By the way SSL appears to be deprecated in openldap and it's better to use TLS. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ldap.html search for "OpenLDAP SDK". Configuration is the same except you will use port 389 and not use "ldaps://" in the uri.